# How can exculde the data in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to exclude that orders which in my orderRequest table, but it show only that orders which is in orderRequest table and exclude the others.Function get the right id's of orders but it not exclude that orders. It exclude the other orders and show that orders which already in orderRequest table

View.py

```
class OrderProduct_View(TemplateView):

     template_name = 'purchase/orderProduct.html'

     def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         allOrder = OrderProduct.objects.all()
         allOrd = Order.objects.all()
         categories = Category.objects.all()
         categoryId = self.request.GET.get('SelectCategory')
         product = Product.objects.filter(category_id=categoryId)

     def filter_order(order):
         try:
            orderReq = order.orderRequest
            return orderReq
         except:
            return True

     filteredOrders = list(filter(filter_order, allOrd))
   
     args = {'categories': categories, 'product': product, 'filteredOrders': filteredOrders}

     return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

Model.py

```
class OrderProduct(models.Model):
     product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=90)
     quantity = models.IntegerField()
     order_cancel = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Order(models.Model):
     orderProduct = models.ForeignKey(OrderProduct, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     created_by = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
     destination = models.CharField(max_length=30)
     vendor = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     shipping_cost = models.IntegerField()


class OrderRequest(models.Model):
     order_status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
     order = models.OneToOneField(Order, related_name='orderRequest', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

HTML

```
  {% for allOrders in filteredOrders%}
       {{ allOrders.orderProduct.id }} 
       {{ allOrders.orderProduct.product.name }}
       {{ allOrders.orderProduct.quantity }}
       <button><a href="{% url 'allVendor' %}?product_id={{ allOrders.orderProduct.product.id }}&orderProducts_id={{ allOrders.orderProduct.id }}">Place Order</a></button>
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: If you want to exclude something just add .exclude(). I don't understand what you want to exclude, please carify.

Comment: basically i have two table order-Product and order-Request. I want to exclude those orders which is in order-Request table

Comment: So you want to exclude the ```order``` field in ```class OrderRequest```?

Comment: no i want to exclude the order in order-product table if it exist in order-Request

Comment: you are using `TemplateView` ,so define `get_context_data ` instead of `get`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`isnull` lookup [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#isnull) to find instances which don't have a related instance, so to find `Order` instances which have no `OrderRequest` instances you can use:

```
Order.objects.filter(orderRequest__isnull=True)
```

Hence you can write your view as:

```
class OrderProduct_View(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'purchase/orderProduct.html'
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        filteredOrders = Order.objects.filter(orderRequest__isnull=True)
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        categoryId = self.request.GET.get('SelectCategory')
        product = Product.objects.filter(category_id=categoryId)
        args = {'categories': categories, 'product': product, 'filteredOrders': filteredOrders}
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)
```

---

> **Note**: Class names should be in `PascalCase` so `OrderProductView` instead of <s>`OrderProduct_View`</s>. Variable names should be in
> `snake_case` so `filtered_orders` instead of <s>`filteredOrders`</s>,
> etc. See [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python
> Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: @usmanimtiaz if nothing shows then you have no `Order` instances which are without an `OrderRequest` instance.

Comment: Thanks u my friend

Comment: but is it possible i can exclude the orders from order-product table if it is in order table?

Comment: @usmanimtiaz `OrderProduct.objects.filter(order__isnull=True)`?

Comment: but the issue is how can i use both in my html

Answer (score 0):

A:your function `filter_order` does not work, it always True;

B: `return False`  in your try part

Comment: see my comment at question